# Godot Sentry Crash reporting

Tags: c#, mono, sentry, godot

I'm currently working on a small project in which I'd like to catch crashes using sentry. The project is using the c# implementation for Godot.

Sentry needs to wrap all executing code to catch exceptions.

Is there a general entrypoint where I can place this try/catch block or would I need to add this into every section of the code that is being called by Godot?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Seems more of a question to Godot folks. Does the AppDomain.UnhandledException event fires when there's an error in any of the scripts? Sentry captures that automatically. Otherwise, what's the way to be notified of errors?

Comment: In my regular applications I only need to add it to the regular MainWindow method which contains all required calls.

Comment: There's a pull request that implements [crash reporting into Godot](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/22778) using C++, but it's unlikely to be merged now.

Answer (score 2):

Once it's set-up, the Sentry C# client attaches itself to some dotnet framework exception hooks, like [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netframework-4.8).

So, you're not required to plant try / catch clauses anywhere.

Just initialize the `SentrySDK` object like this:

```cs
SentrySdk.Init(o => {
    o.Dsn = new Dsn("https://451cf9b0fd9e4f0294a0d15b6c36bce2@sentry.io/5170198");
});
```

And the framework should invoke Sentry and create a report on its own.

I recently wrote [an article demonstrating just that](https://gatomalo.dev/blog/2020/03/21/error-monitoring-godot-sentry/).

Answer (score 1):

I have recently implemented Sentry SDK but `AppDomain.UnhandledException` doesn't work in Godot C# mono implementation.
You have to manually catch unhandled exceptions like this:

```csharp
SentrySdk.Init(opts => { opts.Dsn = "<sentry dsn url>"; });

GD.UnhandledException += (sender, args) => {
    if (SentrySdk.IsEnabled) {
        SentrySdk.CaptureException(args.Exception);
    }
};
```

This was added in Godot 3.3+ version https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/46174

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of Godot version 4, they have removed the `GD.UnhandledException` event, so it cannot be subscribed to, and `AppDomain.UnhandledException` still doesn't work, so sentry can't really be used to catch any unhandled and unexpected exceptions for now.

There is an issue opened on the Godot repo along with a PR to fix it, but i doubt it'll be fixed anytime soon amongst the thousands of other issues that are open. The issue can be found [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/73515).